# How to find bounds for $x$ and $y$ for this triple integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, arithmetic

I want to find the volume of the region enclosed by $z=x^2+y^2$ and $z=x+y$. How can I find the bounds for $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the intersection of the two surfaces, i.e.

$$
\begin{cases}
z = x^2 + y^2 \\
z = x + y
\end{cases}
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
x^2 + y^2 = x +y
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
\Big(x-\frac12\Big)^2 + \Big(y-\frac12\Big)^2 = \frac12
$$

so the projection of the intersection onto the $xy$-plane is a circle centered at $(\frac12,\frac12)$ and radius $\frac1{\sqrt2}$. Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 2):

The intersection of the surfaces results in a circle $(x-1/2)^2+(y-1/2)^2 = 1/2$.  Note that, in this circle, $x+y \ge x^2+y^2$.  The integral representing the volume $V$ then becomes

$$V = 2 \int_{\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} dx \: \int_0^{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} - \left ( x - \frac{1}{2} \right )^2}} dy \: \int_{x^2+y^2}^{x+y} dz$$

**EDIT**

Following a suggestion from @mrf, convert to polars in $x$ and $y$:

$$V = \int_0^{2 \pi} d \theta \: \int_0^{1/\sqrt{2}} dr \: \left(\frac{3}{4}- r^2\right) =\frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{3} \pi $$

Comment: If you really want to do the integral for the OP, polar coordinates centered at (1/2,1/2) seems like a much better idea.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that, and I'll follow through, but it is instructive to see it in rectangulars.

Comment: Shouldn't you integrate $z$ from $x+y$ to $x^2 + y^2$?

Comment: @PaulManta: No.  See my second sentence.